# how to create a 2*2 block sparse matrix in python?

Tags: matrix, block

I have a dense matrix A like A = np.random.rand(100, 100), I need to create a sparse matrix (block anti-diagonal matrix) as

( 0  A )
(A^t 0 )

to make it symmetric so I can use eigsh to get some eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Could someone please provide some code snippet in python for this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: m=A.shape[0]
XX =np.block([[np.zeros((m, m)),  A],  [A.T, np.zeros((m, m))] ])

just use np.block to create a new matrix for testing first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**sklearn** helps us in making sparse matrix using `make_sparse_spd_matrix`

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_sparse_spd_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prec = make_sparse_spd_matrix(1000, alpha=0.98)
plt.spy(prec)
```

**matplotlib** helps us to view the sparse matrix, Hope you find it useful too :)